# Adding formula which contains nested IF's to range not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am a point in my project where I need to add forumulas to various columns (ranges) in my spreadsheet.  The first of such takes a value within a cell, and returns another value.  This should be the same value down the entire column.

I tried using the actual formula, and it has a problem with the IF's. Although this is how it is stated in Excel and works fine, when I try to add it using VBA, it has an issue with the statement, and the = signs.

So, rather than sorting out that issue, I tried a different approach, as the initial value it needs to find and compare, is the result of a combo box.  In an earlier step, I had placed this value in the column I am grabbing the initial value from. This is the month the report is being updated for.  What I am trying to achieve, is the value of the last month it was ran.

For instance if the value of the initial cell, is "December", the previous month would be "November" and that is the result that would be placed into the designated cell within the same row.  I cannot get this to work either. It doesn't error, it just passes right through it.

I am open to either placing the formula below into the range AN2 to lRowB (this is the last row from another variable)  - or - doing it using a variable in the macro itself (approach 2). Whatever makes the most sense and performs the best. This sheet has over 20k entries.

The formula is:

`=IF([@[Current Update Month]]="January", "December", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="February", "January", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="March", "February", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="April", "March", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="May", "April", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="June", "May", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="July", "June", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="August", "July", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="September", "August", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="October", "September", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="November", "October", IF([@[Current Update Month]]="December", "November", 0))))))))))))`

The other approach is what I was last using in my code.

Here is a snippet.

```
Dim lastMonthUpdate As String
Dim lastUpdateMonRng As Range

Set lastUpdateMonRng = sht.Range("AN2" & lRowB)
'LRowB is defined in a previous step. The value is this: lRowB = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - it did not need restating

If ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "January" Then
    lastMonthUpdate = "December"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "February" Then lastMonthUpdate = "January"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "March" Then lastMonthUpdate = "February"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "April" Then lastMonthUpdate = "March"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "May" Then lastMonthUpdate = "April"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "June" Then lastMonthUpdate = "May"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "July" Then lastMonthUpdate = "June"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "August" Then lastMonthUpdate = "July"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "September" Then lastMonthUpdate = "August"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "November" Then lastMonthUpdate = "September"
    ElseIf ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "December" Then lastMonthUpdate = "November"

End If
With lastUpdateMonRng = lastMonthUpdate
End With
```

Comment: Am I correct in summarising your question as such: I need a formula that will replace a month's name with the preceding month?

Comment: It is not replacing. It is looking at the value in a cell that contains the update month, which is also the result of the ABCMatrixSelect.ComboBox1.value, and placing the previous month name, in column AN.  It does not replace the original contents, it looks at one cell value, and determines the value. Or.. it can use the ABCMatrixSelect.Combox1.value itself. Either approach would yield same result.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit unclear. I meant exactly what you say. But you need this to be in a VBA macro? Feels like a lookup/index+match would do the trick without having to go to VBA.

Comment: This macro has is about 14 pages long. It makes a report, then 4 other reports.This is not me being a newbie trying to find a quick macro to accomplish this. :), lol! I promise you. It has been an undertaking. I need it in VBA in a step, as I am then using this in another step to compare value of designated cells month over month, if they have changed.  the user requirements wants this stated.

Comment: If your procedure is **14 pages long** you have a SERIOUS problem with it. Break it down, **extract smaller, specialized procedures and functions**, refactor it to death. A procedure should do one thing; a procedure that does 5 reports is a sign that something has gotten out of hand. Break it up. Then break up the smaller pieces.

Comment: What I mean by that is, I don't have a macro that is calling open a bunch of other subroutines. I have one macro that performs all the steps, each in their own block. The combination of all of these "steps" is around 14 pages. I am a workflow writer, so you will have to forgive me. VBA is obviously new to me, which is why I am struggling with some of the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Call the below function with the name of the month and it will return you the previous months name

```
Function GetPreviousMonth(ByVal sMonthName As String) As String
    GetPreviousMonth = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate("01/" & sMonthName & "/2000"))))
End Function
```

I've got it setup as below:
[image]

Comment: I don't want to call other routines to achieve this when all the information is directly in same module. I already capture the date from the user entry in the combobox at the very beginning. This information is then used to determine reference cells to place information on by month. It is much more a complex macro, this is only a snippet, it is going almost 14 pages, and makes several reports.

Comment: It would be much easier to use this method of calling another routine, or at least using the code within the routine.  Just replace your whole `IF...END IF` block with `lastmonthupdate = getpreviousmonth(ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value)`, or if you don't want the routine just use `lastmonthupdate = MonthName(Month(DateAdd("m", -1, CDate("01/" & ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value))))`

Comment: As @DarrenBartrup-Cook mentioned, if you don't want to use it as a routine, just replace your `IF..ElseIF` statement with this. It's a much better approach

Answer (score 1):

`=[@[Current Update Month]]`
returns the *name* of the current month (or the value held in the column called *Current Update Month*).

`=DATEVALUE("1-" & [@[Current Update Month]])`
takes the name of the current month and turns it into a real date - the first of the current month.  This is the same as writing the formula `=DATEVALUE("1-January")`

`=EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1-" & [@[Current Update Month]]),-1)`
returns the last day of the previous month.  This is the same as writing `=EOMONTH("1/01/2017",-1)`.

**Final formula:**
`=TEXT(EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1-" & [@[Current Update Month]]),-1),"mmmm")`
returns the name of the previous month.  This is the same as writing `=TEXT("31/12/2017","mmmm")`

Just read the VBA part, in which case I'd use @Zacs answer and use the calculation directly in the code if you don't want the (in my opinion) simpler method of putting it all in a small function.  Although I wouldn't add the year to the CDATE (leaving that off defaults to this year).

Comment: It is a month. There is no value of the actual day be entering. This value comes from Combobox1. This combo box is the 12 calendar months. The user picks one from a drop down. It is never a value with year, or day, and the value has to be the month before. for the AN column.  I am not inputting any formulas into the sheet, they don't stay.

Comment: Did you actually try the formula?  There doesn't need to be a value with a year or day, just the text of the month.  If you want a VBA solution then Zacs would be the way to go in my opinion.  Other than that, as @MatsMug said, I'm going to smile and wave and go find another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the macro approach.  Macros are much better at handling multiple conditional statements.  You could have the macro get called by an event, you could make a custom formula in excel using the macro, or you could manually call the macro when you need it.  Below is the main piece of how to get the multiple conditions to work in VBA.

In VBA, every `If` statement needs to be ended with an `End If` statement. Instead of creating multiple `If` statements, use `Else If` to put a multiple conditions into the same `If` statment

```
    If ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "January" Then 
        lastMonthUpdate = "December"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "February" Then lastMonthUpdate = "January"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "March" Then lastMonthUpdate = "February"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "April" Then lastMonthUpdate = "March"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "May" Then lastMonthUpdate = "April"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "June" Then lastMonthUpdate = "May"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "July" Then lastMonthUpdate = "June"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "August" Then lastMonthUpdate = "July"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "September" Then lastMonthUpdate = "August"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "November" Then lastMonthUpdate = "September"
        ElseIF ABCMatrixMonthSelect.ComboBox1.value = "December" Then lastMonthUpdate = "November"

    End If
```

Comment: Yes! I did forget this. I have been using Select and Case allot lately, but this isn't something that needs to be selected, and totally forgot my ELSEIF.  I copied this and pasted it into my macro...  it is not working. It doesn't throw an error. It just goes right through it. No where in my column AN is there any previous month value. :( @Jarom

Comment: Updating my snippet above with what my macro is reflecting, with your changes.  I am also including value in a comment of the lRowB, as it is set in a previous step, and didn't need restating, incase that is creating conflict.

Comment: Are you wanting this snippet to populate multiple rows in column AN?  If so, is the snippet in a loop?  Or are you just wanting it to be able to populate one column in AN?

Comment: It needs to do all cells in AN from AN2 to last row. I have last row already defined as lRowB  so I am reusing it, verses declaring another variable/statement.  It is 20k entries, and all the values will be the same.  So whatever the result is from say.. if the report month was September, and the previous month (lastmonthupdate) would then be August.  Whatever is in AN2, would be literally the same, from AN2 to last row of AN. So it could even copy, and paste that value from AN3 to Last row of AN (lRowB).

Comment: Oh I get it now.  The set up for `latMonthUpdate` is not concatenated correctly try this `Set lastUpdateMonRng = sht.Range("AN2:AN" & lRowB)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd find a way to have to comboboxes have the month names as "labels" and a number between 1 and 12 as "values". Then you can get the "previous month" with something as trivial as:

```
=If(@[Current Update Month]=1, 12, @[Current Update Month]-1)
```

That gives you a number between 1 and 12 though; you can have a little UDF exposing `VBA.Strings.MonthName`:

```
Public Function MonthName(ByVal Index As Long) As String
    MonthName = VBA.Strings.MonthName(Index)
End Function
```

And then you can amend the formula to be:

```
=MonthName(If(@[Current Update Month]=1, 12, @[Current Update Month]-1))
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a lookup table:

```
Current   |  Previous
==========|==========
January   |  December
February  |  January
March     |  February
April     |  March
May       |  April
June      |  May
July      |  June
August    |  July
September |  August
October   |  September
November  |  October
December  |  November
```

And then you can replace that huge nested `If` formula with a simple lookup. The "month index minus one" approach strikes me as more efficient though.

Comment: I actual use that for my users to select which month they are going to update. It then references specific cells for that month, to update. Unless I am going to somehow first tell it if the combobox = January, the value is a numeric reference, then build that into an equation which will then some how provide December as the previous update month in column AN, starting at row 2 to last row.. then I am not sure how this would work.

Comment: I've no idea what you just said, so I'm just going to smile and wave. You have everything you need to succeed right here on this page - if not with this answer, then with another. If not, you need to edit your question to clarify, perhaps include a screenshot of your spreadsheet.

Comment: I am saying current update month will always be a month name. It will never be a date in the format of mm/dd/yyyy.  It is the value of combobox1, when the user selects a month name (not inputs any date) from a drop down list containing all 12 months. The value will always be text.

Comment: ActiveX combobox controls' items have a `Value` and a `Label`. You're using the `Label` as a `Value`. Look into it - you can very well have a combobox selection with a `Value` of `1` with `January` as a value for `Text`.

Comment: I understand. I no longer need to use this approach. I am going to just focus on the actual comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A few things here to tackle:

1) you are using table references [@[Current Update Month]], so the column "AN2" has to next to the table for the reference to work. If you use this type of reference, it will work anywhere
=if(Table1[Current Update Month].
2) you are also comparing text values, to put that into VBA you will need to use CHR(34) to input double quotes. Here is a short bit of code to add a formula to a range of cells that reference a table

```
Let sht.Range("AN2" & lRowB).Formula = "=if([@[Current Update Month]]=" & Chr(34) & "January" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "December" & Chr(34) & ", IF([@[Current Update Month]]=" & Chr(34) & "March" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "February" & Chr(34) & ",IF([@[Current Update Month]]=" & Chr(34) & "July" & Chr(34) & "," & Chr(34) & "June" & Chr(34) & ")))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a solution which works without macros and easy to follow:
1) Add a column with a formula which translates months from text to numeric, for example, "January" to 1:
`=MONTH(DATEVALUE(C4&"1"))`

2) Add another column which subtracts one month:
`=IF(D4=1,12,D4-1)`

3) Add the last column which translates months from numeric to text, for example, 2 to "February":
`=TEXT(DATE(2010,E4,1);"mmmm")`

That's all. For 20k rows should not be a big deal.
[image: One month back example]

**EDITED**:
Steps 1-3 can be converted to a sinlge line formula:
`=TEXT(DATE(2010,IF(MONTH(DATEVALUE(C4&"1"))=1,12,MONTH(DATEVALUE(C4&"1"))-1),1),"mmmm")`